# why Object is not callable at the second time of execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use run the following code. The code generates output for the first time, however during the 2nd execution returns an error -- TypeError: 'YahooSecurity' object is not callable

I am not sure why this is happening. I am using the following python package https://pypi.org/project/pypf/

My code is -

```
import os
import time
from pypf.chart import PFChart
from pypf.instrument import YahooSecurity
symbol  = "TATAPOWER","TATAMOTORS"
for i in symbol:
    print(i)
    YahooSecurity = YahooSecurity(i, True, True, '1d',1)
    print(type(YahooSecurity))
    chart = PFChart(YahooSecurity,0.01,1,'C',3,True,True,True)
    chart.create_chart(dump=True)
    time.sleep(20)
```

"TATAPOWER","TATAMOTORS" are csv file with data

Error -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [38], line 9
      7 for i in symbol:
      8     print(i)
----> 9     YahooSecurity = YahooSecurity(i, True, True, '1d',1)
     10     print(type(YahooSecurity))
     11     chart = PFChart(YahooSecurity,0.01,1,'C',3,True,True,True)

TypeError: 'YahooSecurity' object is not callable
```

I am trying to get multiple charts in one go.

Comment: Why do you assign an instance of the class to a variable with the identical name as the class?

Comment: But `YahooSecurity = YahooSecurity(...)` overwrites your import. You should use another name, eg: `ys = YahooSecurity(...)`

Answer (score 1):

because `YahooSecurity = YahooSecurity(i, True, True, '1d',1)` replaces the object with *the result* of calling the object (or, more likely, the class). So, the second time you use it, it's not a class anymore. Just make it somethin like `yahoo_security = YahooSecurity(i, True, True, '1d',1)`